# The app freezes while debug

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, freeze

I am new in Android and I faced to a problem. I use android studio 2.3, and everything was fine. But after some time, i spotted that an app hangs while i debug. It freeze and works pretty slow. If i turn off debug the app works fine. I tried to clean cach on device and studio but it did not help. I set the my laptop aside and continued work on other pc. In the beginning everything was good but problem returns. I cant figure out the reason and fix it. Has anybody face same problem?

---

Проблема приложение тормозит во время отладки. Без оной работает нормально. Продолжил работать за другим pc и все было хорошо сперва, но проблема вернулась. Пробовал чистить кешь, удалять но не помогает. Как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As WieFel wrote, debugger will obviously stop at any breakpoints you created. Make sure that you are not setting your breakpoints on whole methods, as it can cause your debugger to be incredibly slow. Breakpoints should be ideally targeted at single lines of code. You can see all of the breakpoints you've set by **Run... -> View Breakpoints** or **Cmd/Ctrl + Shift + F8**.

Comment: That actually has helped... so disturbing that the IDE won't even show what breakpoint it hangs on, just freezes the app completely

Comment: this was it for me. didn't find out which one, i guess i just had too many breakpoints...  it looked like Android Studio was hanging but that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in debug mode, the app stops at the breakpoints you have set in your code. This gives you the opportunity to look at the variable values at that point in code.
To continue the execution you have to click on the green **resume** button on the top left of the debug view. -> image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQBeI.png)